# jQuery replace specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

Simply, How can I replace exact text with HTML using jQuery?

The original text is *`View All Customer Reviews`*

I want it to be replaced with `<span class="redbutton">View All Reviews &#187;</span>`

Thanks.

Comment: Is this text in some html element?

Comment: Yes, an anchor, but the anchor is not classified nor identified

Comment: you shouldn't need jQuery for this.  Javascript has a built in regex match/replace functionality.

Comment: @Brombomb Would you happen to have a solution?

Comment: The solution by @Wally-Qiao below is perfectly acceptable

Comment: But the content isn't wrapped in a `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="_div">xxx|||View All Customer Reviews|||xxx</div>
<script>
$(function() {
var html = $('#_div').html() + '';
html = html.replace(/View All Customer Reviews/g, '<span class="redbutton">View All Reviews &#187;</span>');
$('#_div').html(html);
});
</script>
```

// ===================----==================  ///

```
<a>xxx|||View All Customer Reviews|||xxx</a>
<a>yyy|||View All Customer Reviews|||yyy</a>
<a>zzz|||View All Customer Reviews|||zzz</a>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function(i) {
        var html = $(this).html() + '';
        html = html.replace(/View All Customer Reviews/g, '<span class="redbutton">View All Reviews &#187;</span>');
        $(this).html(html);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: My content isn't wrapped in a div

Comment: If you provided what your content is wrapped in we'd be able to help you more specifically.  This solution show how to use jQuery to grab the contents of any html element by `id` and then replace the text.

Comment: @Brombomb I know I understand the content is wrapped in an unclassified anchor

Comment: use `$('a')` to grab all anchors.  You should be able to narrow this down somewhat with some parent div/class selector.

Comment: I tried to modify the script to this, but it didn't work: `$(function() {
var html = $('a:contains('View All Customer Reviews')').html() + '';
html = html.replace(/View All Customer Reviews/g, '<span class="redbutton">View All Reviews &#187;</span>');
$('a:contains('View All Customer Reviews')').html(html);
});
`

Comment: i've posted the answer you want @user1090389

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).html() + ''`? `.html()` also accepts a function, so you could just do `$('a').html(function(i, html) { return html.replace(...); });`.

Comment: just easy to read, someone would know the type & it's foreach iteration at first sight @FelixKling

Comment: Okay... I've been able to verify this works. But it doesn't work on my site: my code `<a href="/ReviewsList.asp?ProductCode=LC70LE732U&amp;Reviews=Y">View 
      All Customer Reviews</a>` The problems is, my site has a line break and a bunch of spaces between "View" & "All" Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nGgxu/1/ Do you know how to make it work with my site.

Comment: you'r using <br> for line break, try this html.replace(/View(\s*<br>\s*)All Customer Reviews/g, '<span class="redbutton">View All Reviews &#187;</span>')   @user1090389

Comment: else if using \r\n and tabs, html.replace(/View(\s*[\r\n|\t]\s*)All Customer Reviews/g, ...) @user1090389

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/